# Logging user actions in Wicket

Tags: logging, user-interface, wicket, event-sourcing

I'm experimenting with Wicket and event sourcing. I'm trying to log the user actions, so we can replay them or use them for testing or demoing purposes.

What would you recommend as strategy?

For example, I could define action classes and put them in the onsubmit etc. Or override all the 'action' components of wicket, e.g. the link, button, text field. Etc.

Any good advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [request logger](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/IRequestLogger.html) provided with Wicket out of the box since 1.2 (though its implementation has changed considerably over the years). This logs the request targets and responses in a (in 6.0, see wicket-extensions) JSON format for parsing. Note that depending on the number of users this can generate an unwieldy log.

Comment: It seems the request logger can log the *class* of the component, but not the instance itself. What would be a good approach to get the instance?

Comment: See the IRequestLogger#logEventTarget method (http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/IRequestLogger.html#logEventTarget(org.apache.wicket.request.IRequestHandler)) and IComponentRequestTarget to get the instance of the component

Answer (score 4):

**WARNING:** This is **NOT** a solution to the problem. It **might** work for ajax only but I'm not sure about that either.

You could use an [IComponentInstantiationListener](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/application/IComponentInstantiationListener.html) to check for new Components beeing created and whether the're clickable or not. Then you could attach a Logging-Behavior. This way you could easily switch your logging on and off in one place and wouldn't have to subclass every Link-, Button, and Whatnot-class to do the logging.

Comment: I got the idea, but how can a behaviour 'grab' the onClick method in for example a Link? OR will this only work for Ajax enabled links and can I override the default AjaxClick event?

Comment: @RobAu Good point. I never did this myself but I'm sure I saw this somewhere. I think you'd have to implement `IBehaviourListener` in your Behaviour and put the logging part into the onRequest method. I'll come back to you later with a more definite answer if you need one.

Comment: Hi Nicktar, looked  into the IBehaviorListener, but I am still a little bit at loss as how to get the onclick from the request. Any hints on that?

Comment: @RobAu I've tried for a couple of houres both to find out where I saw this or how it's supposed to work but I failed. I'm terribly sorry having wasted your time. I tried to delete my answer but I can't since it's accepted. Again, I'm sorry.

Comment: Please leave the answer, it provides insight in methods and ideas. I removed the accepted tick mark. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Wicket itself doesn't provide hooks for something like this but depending on the other technologies you use you can do it in the persistency layer - e.g. with JPA's @PreRemove, @PreUpdate, @PrePersist.
Another approach is Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP).

Answer (score 0):

Considering every user action is a http request ajax or classic, you can log every request  (every request has a component path) with some identifiers you need. In Wicket 1.4 you extend the request cycle, in 1.5+ add a request cycle listener.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/requestcycle-in-wicket-15.html